# Slider revolution is not working autoplay on window browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have use demo agency video slider revolution Jquery. I have try to set autoplay but problem is not work on window browser but mobile browser work fine. I have also use below code.

Jquery:

```
//stopLoop:"on",
 stopAtSlide: -1,
 stopAfterLoops: -1,
```

Comment: What browsers are you using? In windows if you are using IE then make sure that you are using IE9+.

Comment: @Mohit Thank you for answer but problem is resolved. I have miss the autoplay="true" in li that's way autoplay is not working.